# How to prevent clearInterval from breaking setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, clearinterval

I'm a third party javascript developer and one of my clients has the following code on their page, which gets run repeatedly:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
}
```

This of course breaks my `setInterval` loop. I figured I'd work around that by just using a `setTimeout` which creates another `setTimeout` if some conditions aren't met yet. Much to my surprise, the `clearInterval` code above **also** breaks my timeout.

You can observe this behavior without even creating a `setTimeout` loop, but just a solitary timer (I wrapped it in some extra code to keep it off the window):

```
var example = (function(){
  return {
    foo: setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('bar');
    }, 5000)
  };
}());

for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
}
```

The only thing I can think to do if overwrite the built in clearInterval to not clear out my timer specifically, but that seems very very wrong and dirty to me.

```
var originalClearInterval = window.clearInterval;

var exampleLoop = setInterval(function() {
  console.log('loop running');
  if(typeof window.stopRunning !== 'undefined' && window.stopRunning === true) {
    window.clearInterval = originalClearInterval;
    clearInterval(exampleLoop);
    console.log('loop finished');
  }
}, 50);

window.clearInterval = function(timerId) {
  if(timerId !== exampleLoop) {
    originalClearInterval.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is basically because they are using [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) completely the wrong way

Comment: Set your interval to a variable, so you can `clearInterval(intervalID)` instead of clearing everything.

Comment: @Rhumborl - Correct.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Unfortunately because I'm a third party developer I can't modify the code that's on the client site and stop them from doing the awful clearInterval loop

Comment: There is no difference between timers created with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, when it comes to the “identifier” that those methods return – you can use `clearInterval` _or_ `clearTimeout` _interchangeably_ to clear them. // A hardcore, kill-all script like that says/shouts in rather clear words, “we don’t want any timers or intervals to run on our page, period.” Your client should make up their mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be interesting to know **why** they run that ugly piece of code...

Anyway, your idea to write something **uglier** is a step in the right direction, but you can push the ugliness a notch, without touching their own function (you're a third party, remember - I'm surprised you even have the right to *look* at their code). You won't even have additional id management to do:

```
function setBulletproofTimeout( code, delay ) {

    var minId = 99999;
    var id = 0;
    var myIntervals = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i<=minId; i++) {
       id = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
       if( id >= minId ) {
            // that's the One, kill the others
            myIntervals.forEach( function( e ) { window.clearInterval( e ); } );
            return id;
       }
       else {
            myIntervals.push( id );
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general I like this answer, but I think it would be better to `return id;` instead of `break;` so that we can still clear the timer properly (and conform to the setTimeout/setInterval api). My one concern with this approach is that it could break _their_ code by causing their code to creating timers outside the range that they need to clear (because all the lower id's will have already been used)

Comment: @BeauLynn-Miller you're right, I'll change it. About your concerns, I really think (joke aside) that the right way to handle this situation is to understand why they are doing that and act accordingly. Else, you're in a kind of "undefined behavior" zone, you can't be sure to do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks @Ilya. Yes, you're right. I've read their code and as far as I can tell the only reason they're doing that is because they're lazy, but they may know something I don't.

Comment: So, your understanding is that they do that just because they won't bother tracking their own timer IDs ? You could suggest a simple code to manage that and wrap their `setTimeout` calls, that's quite easy. Tell them that as it is, they risk breaking lib / plugins code, not only your code...

Answer (score 0):

So there is way: place your setTimeout call into an isolated place like a `WebWorker` or an `IFrame`, then provide some events to listen on.

I understand it is a hack for just a setTimeout, but a better one then replacing clearInterval.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think is to play dirty too - redefine window.clearInterval, to ignore clears for your timeout ids:

```js
// create an array to store timeout IDs to ignore.
window.ignoreTimeoutIds = [];

// store original clearInterval function as another property
window.clearInterval2 = window.clearInterval;

// redefine clearInterval to not clear if it is one of your timeoutIds
window.clearInterval = function(intervalId) {
  if (window.ignoreTimeoutIds.indexOf(intervalId) > -1)
    console.log('not clearing 1'); // for demo purposes
  else
    window.clearInterval2(intervalId);
};


(function() {

  //set the timeout and get its  ID
  var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('bar');
    // don't forget to remove the timeoutId from the ignore list
    window.ignoreTimeoutIds.splice(window.ignoreTimeoutIds.indexOf(timeoutId))
  }, 5000);

  // add the timeoutID to the ignore list
  window.ignoreTimeoutIds.push(timeoutId);
}());

for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
  window.clearInterval(i);
}
```

You could also create a wrapper for `setTimeout()` to handle adding and removing from the array if you want that part to be neater.

Comment: OK didn't see your edit... yes it is wrong and dirty but they didn't set a good baseline for "good coding"